# WSUS on 2012R2 HUGE amount of files

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, windows-update

I am setting up a new WSUS server on Server 2012 R2. I have the settings down to English and only the systems we have, as well as Language Packs for those turned off Drivers are also turned off. When I do the initial sync, I get over 200GB of updates.  (Critical, Definitions, Security, Service Packs, Update Rollups, and updates for Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2, 2012 R2, Exchange 2013, and Office 2003-2016.)

I must be missing something in config as everything I'm reading says that 50-70GB is a LOT. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're downloading all the available updates for 7 (or 11 or 12, you don't specify architecture) operating systems, 5 (or 10, you don't specify architecture) versions of Office, and a version of Exchange.  ~200 GB sounds about right.  Excluding superseded updates, if you haven't already, might help, as well as dropping any of those OSes or products that you can.

Comment: Thanks. At this point we have to be able to update all these. i was seeing much smaller numbers, but at the same time they didn't state what OS and software. Sorry about not mentioning the architecture, both 32 and 64. Is there a way to block download of superseded updates? I have it set to not download until approved, but I don't even want to see the superseded updates.

Comment: @Tmacie Well, you would go through and decline them to make that happen, but [it's a headache](http://serverfault.com/a/618573/118258), especially when you're still dealing with XP.  Unless you're really hard up for disk space, you probably have better uses for your time than declining old updates to free up a few GB.

Comment: Yeah, tell me about it. I wish they'd build in better management. Thanks for your help and guidance.

Comment: A note for those in the future - Win7 through 10 and server 2008r2 through 2016, 1 version of exchange, latest 3 versions of office - initial approval w/ express update files and cumulative update files is 400GB+ for me now. Single language